# Send JavaScript variables from a js file to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to send variables (username+password) from a js function inside a .js file, to a PHP file, and store them inside the file.

I tried to use ajax but it doesn't work for me:

```
function func(){
var user = ...
var pass = ...
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"myphp.php",
  data: user,
  success: function(){
      alert("success!");
  },
  error: function(){
      alert("error!")
  }
});
}
```

when I open the PHP file I see nothing.

**EDIT: my problem is much more basic. My ajax code just doesn't run inside the function. I have a .js file that contains only one function (the function above) and the ajax code doesn't get executed. I get no success nor error messages.**

Comment: Doesn't work is not a problem description. Please include details like what you expect, what is happening instead, etc. Also, inspect the network and console tabs in your developer tools to discover any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"myphp.php",
  data: {user: user, password: pass},
  success: function(data){
      alert(data);
  }
});
```

PHP won't have any problems parsing this, since jQuery automatically sends it in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you need to send JSON and have PHP read JSON, then that's a different story.

Comment: Is there a specific code I should include in my PHP file in order to see the result from the query?

Comment: Well, it's being sent as POST, so `myphp.php` needs to understand it's post. So doing `echo $_POST['user'];` will display the user passed. Try this: `var_dump($_POST);` to figure out what all is passed.